# How to link in order to obtain the names of restaurant

Tags: haskell

I want to obtain the names of restaurant with the level rating result for the restaurant by a service(supervisor). I manage to find a way to filter the name of service(supervisor) and a way to print out the data.

The first code filters out the name of service(supervisor) and second code shows the restaurant output. Service represents the supervisor. The database contains the list of restaurant details.

I am unsure of how to link the first function for filtering from database to the second function for outputting the filtered result.

The type of input for terminal

```
ratedListStr "Colin" testDatabase
```

The output which I want to achieve

```
[Restaurant "03" "John" "Orchard" 6 [9]
```

This is my code below.

```
data Restaurant = Restaurant ResID Brand Area Stars [(Service, LevelRating)]

type Database = [Restaurant]

testDatabase = [
               Restaurant "09" "Chef Kang's" "Rochor" 1
               [("Colin", 4), ("Sam", 7), ("Petrina", 6)],

               Restaurant "10" "Corner House" "Tanglin" 1
               [("Bryan", 7),("Colin", 4),("Nixon", 5), ("Nixon", 7), ("Sam", 5)]

]

-- restaurant service
getService :: Restaurant -> [Service]
getService (Restaurant _ _ _ _ xs) = map fst xs

--filter name of supervisor
restaurantService :: Service -> [Restaurant] -> [Restaurant]
restaurantService se = filter (elem se. getService)

--display output of restaurant
ratedListStr :: Restaurant -> String
ratedListStr (Restaurant rid br ar st s) = "\nRestaurantID: " ++ rid ++ "\n Brand: " ++ br ++ "\n Area: " ++ ar ++ "\n Star: " ++ show st ++ "\n Service Rating" ++ show s
```

Comment: Could you give one or two examples of what you want your new chunk of code to do? What inputs would you provide to it, and what outputs would it respond with?

Comment: Anyway, it's not totally clear, but you might like to look at some or all of these list-management functions: `map`, `concat`, `unlines`, `unwords`.

Comment: So it is impossible to merge this two for the output?

Comment: What you want is almost certainly possible. But we can't say more, because we don't understand what you want. See my first comment above for one way of telling us more about what you want.

Comment: I have modified the question with the input and output as well rephrase my question. Is it better?

Comment: Well, it's what I asked for. But it... remains a bit confusing. Are you sure that your sample output and your example `testDatabase` match up correctly? If so, can you describe in words how the output is computed?

Comment: Sorry, I just need give names of restaurant (brand) and service rating from the chosen supervisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need give names of restaurant (brand) and service rating from the chosen supervisor.

Maybe you need on this function:

```
getBrand :: Restaurant -> Brand
getBrand (Restaurant _ brand _ _ _) = brand

getServices :: Restaurant -> [(Service, LevelRating)]
getServices (Restaurant _ _ _ _ services) = services

takeRating :: Service -> [Restaurant] -> [(Brand, LevelRating)]
takeRating service restaurants = do
    restaurant <- restaurants
    case find (\(s, r) -> s == service) (getServices restaurant) of
        Nothing -> mempty
        Just (_, rating) -> return (getBrand restaurant, rating)
```

This function return list of pairs brand of restaurant and its service rating for the chosen supervisor.

Comment: Sorry Sergey, about Just (_, rating) part, it is for brand and level rating output? 
For this line Nothing -> mempty, what does it mean?

Comment: @TitaniaLo in the code above written the following: look over all restaurant one by one, and for each restaurant from the list look for given service, and if he found (it is `Just (_, rating) -> ...`), return pair of brand and rating (`return (...)`), else (it is `Nothing -> ...`) return "nothing" (`mempty`). In other word, for each element of list `restaurants` either replace restaurant to pair or delete restaurant.

Comment: @TitaniaLo you can find out more information about it if you type in Google or Hoogle what is Monoid and Monad